# GeoDjango: GDAL library is not available to transform() geometry

Tags: gdal, geodjango, geos, django

I am trying to take points and buffer them to create polygons in my django project. I queried for points and tried to take the geometry of the first point and transform it to a meters based system (3395) so I can buffer in meters.

```
In [32]: from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point

In [33]: p = workingqueryset[0].geo_location

In [34]: p
Out[34]: <Point object at 0x1cfeb4bf090>

In [35]: p.transform(3395)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GEOSException                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-ee3c41c5bae3> in <module>()
----> 1 p.transform(3395)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py in transform(self, ct, clone)
522
523         if not gdal.HAS_GDAL:
--> 524             raise GEOSException("GDAL library is not available to transform() geometry.")
525
526         if isinstance(ct, gdal.CoordTransform):

GEOSException: GDAL library is not available to transform() geometry.
```

I have gdal installed with python bindings and even have the GDAL_DATA variable set up for postgis. I've never ran into a gdal issue before. I found [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94640/geodjango-transform-not-working) but I definitely have gdal already installed and variables set up.

```
In [36]: import gdal

In [37]: p.transform(3395)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
GEOSException                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-ee3c41c5bae3> in <module>()
----> 1 p.transform(3395)

C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\gis\geos\geometry.py in transform(self, ct, clone)
522
523         if not gdal.HAS_GDAL:
--> 524             raise GEOSException("GDAL library is not available to transform() geometry.")
525
526         if isinstance(ct, gdal.CoordTransform):

GEOSException: GDAL library is not available to transform() geometry.
```