# Add buffer around polygon in meters using GeoDjango

Tags: postgis, geodjango

I'm using GeoDjango with PostGIS. I have a table with a polygon field called "geofence".

I want to add a 5m buffer zone around the polygon.

```
obj.geofence.buffer(5)
```

This results in a huge buffer zone though. Experimentally it looks like the buffer zone is around 500km wide.

It appears that I must somehow do a transformation of my meter unit to the system used by `polygon.buffer`. How can I do that?

Comment: similar to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220264/geodjango-gdal-library-is-not-available-to-transform-geometry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which SRID are you using?

If you are using WGS84, Try this:

```
distance = 5 # distance in meter
buffer_width = distance / 40000000.0 * 360.0
buffered = obj.geofence.buffer(buffer_width)
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31940674/optimal-query-in-geodjango-postgis-for-locations-within-a-distance-in-meters